# How to crop and resize an image for a LiveTile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, crop, image-resizing, live-tile

I would like to be able to add an image to a live tile so that there is no stretching and the image looks normal. I am getting my images from the PhotoChooserTask, which contain images from the medialibrary. As of now I can successfully place an image on a live tile, but it is stretched and the aspect ratio is not correct. How would I be able to find the aspect ratio of the image and crop the image so that it ends up being a square with dimensions 173x173 with no streching? I have followed a couple tutorials found online but nothing seems to accomplish this the way I need it to.

Comment: Load up the image into a WriteableBitmap, and take out a 173x173 chunk from the image (and remember the user might have an image smaller than that!)

Comment: Well, I guess how would I accomplish that is my question. I understand how to resize the image, but assuming that most images will have a 4:3 aspect ratio, and the smallest size is resized to 173, how would i crop the other side (equally on both ends) so that the size also is 173?

Comment: This is a great project: WriteableBitmapEx. It has a "Crop" method, and I've done magical things with it on WP7. http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this by referencing [Resize image for Live Tile - WriteableBitmapEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684474/resize-image-for-live-tile-writeablebitmapex) which proved to have the correct implementation.