# windows phone live tile backgroundimage source and stretch problems

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, live-tile

Im experiencing problems with the background image at a secondary live tile in my windows phone app, it does not stretch and fit the tile properly (it is a .png image)

I get the data and then create my tile data:

```
var tileData = new StandardTileData
        {
            Title = titleString,
            BackContent = contentString,
            BackTitle = backTitleString,
            BackgroundImage = new Uri(httpUrlString)                
        };
```

is there any way to change the stretch or "retemplate" the tile?

Also i found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684474/resize-image-for-live-tile-writeablebitmapex) with a writeablebitmap, but I cannot understand how to give this bitmap as a source, since the backgroundimage property only accepts a Uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resize the image to give it the good aspect ratio (see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684474/resize-image-for-live-tile-writeablebitmapex))

Then you'll have to save the resulting WriteableBitmap in the Isolated Storage, like this:

```
        // save image to isolated storage
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            // use of "/Shared/ShellContent/" folder is mandatory!
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream imageStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/Shared/ShellContent/MyImage.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Create, isf))
            {
                wbmp.SaveJpeg(imageStream, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            }
        }
```

You will then be able to create the tile like this:

```
        StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
        {
            Title = "Title",
            // reference saved image via isostore URI
            BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/MyImage.jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
        };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! unfortunately i still havent solved my problem, i tried resizing this way and i get exceptions when creating the writeablebitmap.then i tried this  BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(img));  
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Width = 173;
            image.Height = 173;
            image.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;            image.Source = bitmapImage;             
            WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(image,null);and then save it as you suggested, but now the image on my tile is black

Comment: What is the size of the original image? What exception do you get?

Comment: the images come from a web source,eg 150 x 106 px also they are in png format, i dont know if thats relevant. the exception is nullreferenceexception, invalid pointer at the writeablebitmap creation

Comment: PNG should be OK. The BitmapImage method should work. Can you try to call writeableBitmap.Invalidate() to force a redraw of the bitmap?

Comment: added writeableBitmap.Invalidate(); before saving, still black :/

Comment: i found the problem, the image wasnt fully loaded, thats why it wasnt rendered! i had to use the imageopened event, im posting the answer now. thank you very much, i am also using your method afterwards

Answer (score 1):

the problem was the image was not fully loaded, and therefore not properly rendered. I used the ImageOpened event and then saved it as Olivier suggested