# How to resize image returned from URL for live tile

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, live-tile

I need to re-size and image that I'm using to update a live tile in a Windows 8 modern app. I'm retrieving the image through a URL and the image is too large for the tile's size limit of 310 x 150. I have to do this for over 80 images so downloading the image itself isn't an option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar on windows phone, take a look on how to do this here: [Resize image for Live Tile - WriteableBitmapEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684474/resize-image-for-live-tile-writeablebitmapex)
Long blog post version: http://depblog.weblogs.us/2012/01/09/resize-images-to-be-used-on-live-tile-windows-phone-7/

I also used the same scenario in windows 8, the example for that can be found here: http://depblog.weblogs.us/2012/06/22/comdaybe-image-manipulation-in-windows-8-metro-app/

BUT this will indeed download the original image first, don't know if it is a big problem?

Comment: No, I guess that won't be a problem I can just delete the image as needed. From what I've read your solution should be exactly what I need. Haven't had a chance to try it out yet, it's crunch time so I had to move on to something else for the moment.

Comment: You don't need to delete it, it's just a memorystream first, only save the resized one and you are fine ;)

Comment: Depechie, any idea on how to cycle between the default tile and the update tile, say every few seconds using local notifications? I seen a reference to the capability on MSDN but couldn't find any real explanation to it.

Comment: Inside the app itself you can set a tile with TileUpdater class [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208628.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208628.aspx)